# How to Send ArrayList into different class

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, baseadapter

I really confused to think the way to send ArrayList into different class, i have  an ArrayList named = AgenList and i want to send it into different class that extend BaseAdapter, is there anyone that can help me to solve my problem..?
this is my source code :
1. MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
List AgenList = new ArrayList();
boolean boolStatusKoneksi=true;
private ProgressDialog Dialog;
protected Context applicationContext;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    new AgenAsyncTask().execute();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new TesAdapter(this));
}
public class AgenAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        Dialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu sebentar...");
        Dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        Dialog.setCancelable(true);
        Dialog.show();
    }
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


String url = ("http://www.abc.com/xyz.php");
              try{
                  JSONParser j=new JSONParser();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = j.takeJson(url);
                  for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                  {
                      JSONObject c  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        if (c.has("atasan")) 
                            map.put("atasan", c.get("atasan").toString());
                        if (c.has("nama_agen")) 
                            map.put("nama_agen", c.get("nama_agen").toString());
                        if (c.has("kode_agen")) 
                            map.put("kode_agen", c.get("kode_agen").toString());
                        if (c.has("no_aaji")) 
                            map.put("no_aaji", c.get("no_aaji").toString());
                        if (c.has("jenis")) 
                            map.put("jenis", c.get("jenis").toString());
                          AgenList.add(map);


                     }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
              return null;
                }
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String arg) {Dialog.dismiss();}
```

As you see, i have an arrayList Named AgenList that containing JSONArray that i want to send into TesAdapter.java
so this is the TesAdapter.java :

```
public class TesAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater layout;

public TesAdapter(MainActivity context) {
layout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
List AgenList = new ArrayList();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (Integer) null;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return 0;
}

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        convertView= layout.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.ATASAN = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.atasan);
        holder.NAMA_AGEN= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nama_agen);
        holder.KODE_AGEN= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.kode_agen);
        holder.NO_AAJI= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.no_aaji);
        holder.JENIS= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jenis);
        return convertView;

    }

}

 class ViewHolder{
    TextView ATASAN;
    TextView NAMA_AGEN;
    TextView KODE_AGEN;
    TextView NO_AAJI;
    TextView JENIS;

}
```

i hope somebody can help me to solve this problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to add an `ArrayList` property to the `BaseAdapter` class.

Then, in the class where you instantiate a `new BaseAdapter`, pass your `ArrayList` in the constructor.

```
public class Foo {
    public void createBaseAdapter() {
        ArrayList arList = new ArrayList();
        BaseAdapter ba = new BaseAdapter(arList);
    }
}

public class BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList arList;
    public BaseAdapter(ArrayList arList) {
        this.arList = arList;
    }
}
```

#### In your case

```
public TesAdapter(MainActivity context, ArrayList list) {
    layout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.AgenList = list; //Declared as a class property
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to pass my ArrayList in the constructor..?

Comment: @AoyamaNanami There you go. Updated with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Using `public static`  modifier.

```
public static List AgenList = new ArrayList();
```

In other class using : `MainActivity.AgenList` to using `AgenList`

Answer (score 0):

According to me. the simplest way is to **public getAgentList** method in your **MainActivity** class which can be called from **TesAdapter**.Offcourse there are other ways also.

Answer (score 0):

> Send ArrayList into different class

use TesAdapter constructor for sending ArrayList from `MainActivity` to `TesAdapter`. you will need to use `onPostExecute` method for adding adapter to `GridView` instead of onCreate method of Activity:

Change TesAdapter  constructor as:

```
public class TesAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 private LayoutInflater layout;
 List AgenList;
 Context context;
 public TesAdapter(Context context,List AgenList) {
 layout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 this.AgenList = AgenList;
}
....
```

and from `onPostExecute` add adapter to GridView as:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String arg) {
 GridView gridview = (GridView)MainActivity.this. findViewById(R.id.gridview);
 gridview.setAdapter(new TesAdapter(MainActivity.this,AgenList));
 Dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: so how about this code :

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new TesAdapter(this));

that i have put at the first code?

Comment: just comment it and also you are not starting AgenAsyncTask. put `new  AgenAsyncTask().execute("");` in onCreate method

Comment: i've started my AsyncTasck at :
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    new AgenAsyncTask().execute();
....}
...

Comment: @AoyamaNanami: move it after setContentView method

Comment: it doesn't work, the logcat said there's something eror in this line : 
 gridview.setAdapter(new TesAdapter(MainActivity.this,AgenList));

Comment: @AoyamaNanami : ok plz post logcat with question

Comment: i've fix it...there's no error, but the writting not displayed... do you know why..?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that arraylist through the construct or of the other class. Create a class member arraylist in other class. Then do this in constructor 
this.agentlist=passedAgentList